# Can I pattern-match a type without writing a custom trait class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

Since C++20 concepts aren't standardized yet, I'm using `static_assert` as a makeshift concept check, to provide helpful error messages if a type requirement isn't met.  In this particular case, I have a function which requires that a type is callable before getting its result type:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
void example() {
  static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>, "Function must be callable");
  using R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>;

  // ...
}
```

In addition, I require that the callable's result must be some kind of `std::optional`, but I don't know what type the optional will hold, so I need to get that type from it:

```
using R = // ...
using T = typename R::value_type;  // std::optional defines a value_type
```

However, this will fail if type `R` doesn't have a `value_type`, e.g. if it's not a `std::optional` as expected.  I'd like to have a `static_assert` to check for that first, with another nice error message if the assertion fails.

I could check for an exact type with something like `std::is_same_v`, but in this case I don't know the exact type.  I want to check that `R` is *some* instance of `std::optional`, without specifying *which* instance it must be.

One way to do that is with a helper trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_optional { static constexpr bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> { static constexpr bool value = true; };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_optional_v = is_optional<T>::value;
```

…and then I can write:

```
static_assert(is_optional_v<R>, "Function's result must be an optional");
```

That works, but it seems a little awkward to pollute my namespace with a helper trait just for a one-off check like this.  I don't expect to need `is_optional` anywhere else, though I can imagine possibly ending up with other one-off traits like `is_variant` or `is_pair` too.

So I'm wondering: **is there a more concise way to do this?**  Can I do the pattern matching on instances of `std::optional` without having to define the `is_optional` trait and its partial specialization?

Comment: Does “concise” mean fewer lines, or just fewer namespace-scope declarations?

Comment: You could create a re-usable trait that would allow you to define `constexpr bool is_optional_v = is_template_of<std::optional, T>::value;` and could be reused for pair/variant with one liners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the suggestion by several respondents, I made a re-usable trait:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Tpl>
struct is_template_instance : std::false_type { };

template <template <typename...> typename Tpl, typename... Args>
struct is_template_instance<Tpl<Args...>, Tpl> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Tpl>
constexpr bool is_template_instance_v = is_template_instance<T, Tpl>::value;
```

…so that I can write:

```
static_assert(is_template_instance_v<R, std::optional>, "Function's result must be an optional");
```

This is just as many lines and declarations as the `is_optional` trait, but it's no longer a one-off; I can use the same trait for checking other kinds of templates (like variants and pairs).  So now it feels like a useful addition to my project instead of a kluge.

Comment: Great idea a re-usable triait :-) - Anyway, I suggest a little improvement: instead of defining a `static constexpr bool value`, you could inherit from `std::false_type` (main template) or `std::true_type` (specialization); this way you inherit the facilities (by example: the `operator()` or the `operator value_type`) that are present in `std::integral_constant`.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I do the pattern matching on instances of `std::optional` without having to define the `is_optional` trait and its partial specialization?

Maybe using implicit deduction guides for `std::optional`?

I mean... something as

```
using S = decltype(std::optional{std::declval<R>()});

static_assert( std::is_same_v<R, S>, "R isn't a std::optional" );
```

Explanation.

When `R` is `std::optional<T>` for some `T` type, `std::optional{r}` (for an `r` value of type `R`) should call the copy constructor and the resulting value should be of the same type `R`.

Otherwise, the type should be different (`std::optional<R>`).

The following is a full compiling example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
bool isOptional ()
 {
   using U = decltype(std::optional{std::declval<T>()});

   return std::is_same_v<T, U>;
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << isOptional<int>() << std::endl;                // print 0
   std::cout << isOptional<std::optional<int>>() << std::endl; // print 1   
 }
```

Anyway, I support the suggestion by super: create a more generic type-traits that receive `std::option` as template-template argument.

Comment: Clever.  I think I'll go with the re-usable trait approach, but I like this idea.  Having seen this, I'll probably find another use for this trick somewhere.  :-)